# How do anonymous functions can solve the default binding error in strict mode?

Tags: javascript

When we use default binding in strict mode the global object is not eligible for the default binding. Then if we use the  below code, we will encounter an error:

```
    function foo() {
    "use strict";

    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

foo(); // TypeError: `this` is `undefined`
```

But when we use an anonymous function as Call-Site,the error disappears.

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

(function(){
    "use strict";

    foo(); // 2
})();
```

So how anonymous function in this code could solve the global object issue and solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the problem, exactly. Any function which is defined inside of a "use strict" scope obeys the "use strict" rules. Any function defined outside of a "use strict" scope doesn't, regardless of where it's called. There are lots of potential problems that can come from not grasping that (or forgetting about it).  Which problems are you referring to? The most upfront advice I could give you there is: Know your codebase; Use strict-mode in new code; Never rely on `window` or `global` to catch your scoping errors, and then it doesn't matter which you use, as regards `this`.

Comment: TypeError: `this` is `undefined`

Comment: Do you mean that you *want* to get the TypeError, or do you mean that you *don't* want to get the TypeError. "use strict" is acting as expected; *what are you trying to accomplish*, what are you *expecting* to do, what is *happening*, and *what would you think should happen instead*?

Comment: I mean in the first case we got a type error but after using anonymous function, the error disappeared! why? How anonymous function could effect this problem and solved the error?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `'use strict'` to the IIFE didn't change the behaviour of `foo`, removing `'use strict'` from `foo` did.

As the comments above have explained, [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is scoped to the function it is typed in.

These examples will behave the same way as your first example.

```js
function foo() {
  'use strict';
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

(function(){
  foo(); // 2
})();
```

```js
function foo() {
  'use strict';
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

(function(){
  'use strict';
  foo(); // 2
})();
```

And these ones will behave the same way as your second example.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

(function(){
  foo(); // 2
})();
```

```js
function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

foo();
```